# Counting the number of working days in a range with entries in DB on those days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with date field and there will be multiple entries for each day. I need to get the count of weekdays having at least one entry in that weekday.

If the date range is 27-Feb-12 till 2-Apr-12 then there are 26 week days and it needs to return 26 if we have entries in all weekdays and a lesser count if there is no entry on a particular day.

Say a table **Transaction** with `tid`, `type`, `createddate`.

Can someone please suggest me a good SQL approach ? I am running on a Oracle DB

Comment: Will your table have entries with **weekend** dates as well?

Comment: Please put what you have tried.

Comment: If you have already made any attempts to solve the problem yourself (even unsuccessfully) please post these queries here.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking down the problem into multiple smaller problems. Here's how..(I am using march-10 instead of april 2nd in your example, to keep the data set smaller).

Get all the dates between the two dates.

```
select to_date('27-feb-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') + level -1
from dual
connect by level < ( to_date('10-mar-12','dd-mon-yy') -
                     to_date('27-feb-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') +2
                   )
TO_DATE('
---------
27-FEB-12
28-FEB-12
29-FEB-12
01-MAR-12
02-MAR-12
03-MAR-12
04-MAR-12
05-MAR-12
06-MAR-12
07-MAR-12
08-MAR-12
```

next, get the weekdays out of this result set..

```
with all_days as (
        select to_date('27-feb-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') + level -1 date1
        from dual
        connect by level < ( to_date('10-mar-12','dd-mon-yy') -
                             to_date('27-feb-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') +2
                           )
)
select  date1,
        to_char(date1,'D'),
        to_char(date1,'Day') Day
from    all_days
where   to_number(to_char(date1,'D')) between 2 and 6 -- monday through friday
/

DATE1     T DAY
--------- - ---------
27-FEB-12 2 Monday
28-FEB-12 3 Tuesday
29-FEB-12 4 Wednesday
01-MAR-12 5 Thursday
02-MAR-12 6 Friday
05-MAR-12 2 Monday
06-MAR-12 3 Tuesday
07-MAR-12 4 Wednesday
08-MAR-12 5 Thursday
09-MAR-12 6 Friday
```

--and finally, your exists logic to check if there is any data for this date in your table.

```
with all_days as (
        select to_date('27-feb-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') + level -1 date1
        from dual
        connect by level < ( to_date('10-mar-12','dd-mon-yy') -
                             to_date('27-feb-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') +2
                           )
)
select  date1,
        to_char(date1,'D'),
        to_char(date1,'Day') Day
from    all_days
where   to_number(to_char(date1,'D')) between 2 and 6 -- monday through friday
  and   exists (
            select 1
            from your_table yt
            where yt.date_column = all_days.date_column
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('02-04-2012','DD-MM-YYYY')-
to_date('27-02-2012','DD-MM-YYYY')- 
2*(to_char(to_date('02-04-2012','DD-MM-YYYY'),'WW')-
to_char(to_date('27-02-2012','DD-MM-YYYY'),'WW'))+1 from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 25 total business days between your dates in 2013 - I used current year. With my hypothetical data you will get 17 total working days with entries. To see all days comment SUM() part and uncomment Start_Date... and other columns. Then you can count visually to check results:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Entry_Val > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) entry_days  --, Start_Date, Wk_Day, Day#, entry_val, lvl
  FROM
  (
   SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27-FEB-12') + LEVEL-1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')   Start_Date
        , TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27-FEB-12') + LEVEL-1, 'DY')            Wk_Day
        , TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27-FEB-12') + LEVEL-1, 'D' )            Day#
        , MOD(LEVEL, 3)                                            Entry_Val -- Hypot. entry day - count only days with entry_val > 0 -- 
        , LEVEL                                                    lvl  -- added for clarity
     FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT to_date('02-APR-12') - to_date('27-FEB-12') days_btwn FROM dual)
  )
  WHERE Wk_Day NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN') -- OR -- Day# NOT IN (1, 7)
  /

ENTRY_DAYS
--------
17
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting this question a little differently. @Pradeep, is this what you're after?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(CreatedDate))
FROM Transaction
WHERE TRUNC(CreatedDate) BETWEEN DATE '2012-02-27' AND DATE '2012-04-02'
  AND TO_CHAR(CreatedDate, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

If you have entries for all Monday-Friday days between 2/27/2012 and 4/2/2012, the result of this query will be 26. It won't matter how many entries there are for any given day, as long as each day has at least one.

If you don't have any records for two of the days (say 2/28 and 3/22) the result will be 24.

Note that I used `TRUNC` in the first and third lines above in case your `CreatedDate` column includes a time component. If it doesn't you can do without the TRUNC.